# CIFS mount Permission Denied

Tags: ubuntu, mount, cifs

I want to preface my question saying that I am relatively weak with Linux and the command line and also StackExchange.

I am trying to set-up a network drive from a different unix machine.

I have followed this [guide on how to permanently mount a network drive](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/map-network-drive-onto-ubuntu-14-04/)

```
sudo mount -a
```

Results in:

```
enter codemount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

My fstab looks like:

```
//[url to server]/[path to my folder to link] [path to local folder to mount] cifs credentials=[path to credentials file],uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

The fstab looks little different as given in the guide but only because I used a template from coleagues that had the exact same set-up with the only difference of it working. The credentials file has the same username and password I use to SSH into the machine.

Verbose mount output was not much helpful either:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=[IP],unc=\\[url]\apriede,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=apriede,prefixpath=projects,pass=********
```

Most problems I found while searching for an answer had an issue with an unset or wrong sec option, which I know should be correct in my instance because it works for my coleagues, so I hope it validates my question as a new one.

Comment: @garethTheRed: Is it important? `mount -a` runs under root anyway.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi - so it did.  I didn't read the question properly :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state that the credentials file contain the same username and password you use to SSH into the machine. This is perhaps not the same.

When you mount a CIFS share, you specify a username that is known to Samba (`smbpasswd -a $newuser`) and this account also needs a UNIX counterpart account, meaning a Samba user, needs a UNIX account with the same name. The password can be different however.

Check if you can manually mount it, and verify your Samba password with `smbpasswd`, or change it to something, then mount it.

It could also be selinux, I am not sure, It could spit out a different error. Check if selinux is enabled on the Samba server

getenforce

If its on Enforcing you can try to disable it temporary;

setenforce 0

And see if it works.

Comment: Original poster states passwords are the same. You casted a doubt on it, but it’s your subjective opinion, neither answer nor a real solution. Familiarize yourself with Stack Exchange’s guidelines on answers, please.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, I also stated I am incompetent :^), so he might very well be right. I got no idea to be honest if the passwords are the same that was just my assumption. I will try to dig into the suggestions of the answer tomorrow and see if brings about any fruit.

Comment: None of the guides and links I came up with in my search pointed out smbpasswd setup side of things. So this was exactly what I needed.